# Sharepoint Compile with project containing two class libraries that referencing each other

Tags: c#, sharepoint, class-library

I have a Sharepoint visual Webpart that references two Class Libraries. The libraries work together to provide the Webpart with values. The solution builds with no errors or warnings....

```
1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: ClassLibrary1, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  ClassLibrary1 -> c:\Projects\TempWebPart\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll
2>------ Rebuild All started: Project: ClassLibrary2, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
2>  ClassLibrary2 -> c:\Projects\TempWebPart\ClassLibrary2\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary2.dll
3>------ Rebuild All started: Project: TempWebPart, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
3>  TempWebPart -> c:\Projects\TempWebPart\TempWebPart\bin\Debug\TempWebPart.dll
========== Rebuild All: 3 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

However when I press the start button to debug it throws errors and wont compile...

```
1>------ Build started: Project: TempWebPart, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
1>  TempWebPart -> c:\Projects\TempWebPart\TempWebPart\bin\Debug\TempWebPart.dll
1>  ClassLibrary1 -> c:\Projects\TempWebPart\ClassLibrary1\bin\Debug\ClassLibrary1.dll
1>c:\Projects\TempWebPart\ClassLibrary2\Class2.cs(5,7,5,20): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ClassLibrary1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 2 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

I also get the following errors and warnings.

```
Error   1   The type or namespace name 'ClassLibrary1' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) c:\Projects\TempWebPart\ClassLibrary2\Class2.cs 5   7   TempWebPart
```

I have added the references to the Webpart project for the two classlibrary projects.
I have also added the "assemblies from project output" for the two class libraries in the Advanced Menu under Package...

```xml
<Solution xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/" SolutionId="0a8bd835-ad91-49a1-a82d-61e22081fbe6" SharePointProductVersion="14.0">
  <Assemblies>
    <Assembly Location="ClassLibrary1.dll" DeploymentTarget="GlobalAssemblyCache" />
    <Assembly Location="ClassLibrary2.dll" DeploymentTarget="GlobalAssemblyCache" />
    <Assembly Location="TempWebPart.dll" DeploymentTarget="GlobalAssemblyCache">
      <SafeControls>
        <SafeControl Assembly="TempWebPart, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=5ef7e45135ca6bea" Namespace="TempWebPart" TypeName="*" />
      </SafeControls>
    </Assembly>
  </Assemblies>
  <FeatureManifests>
    <FeatureManifest Location="TempWebPart_Feature1\Feature.xml" />
  </FeatureManifests>
</Solution>
```

My libraries are simple just to test this case.. Here is the code...

```cs
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        public String Hello = "Hello";
    }
}
```

```cs
using ClassLibrary1;

namespace ClassLibrary2
{
    public class Class2
    {
        public String Hello = new ClassLibrary1.Class1().Hello;
    }
}
```

The assemblies are signed. I have tried in a WindowsForms application and is working fine. I have tried vb libraries and a similar message appears. I guess I am missing a step somewhere. I am using vs2012.

I am really stuck on things to try :( I would appreciate any help.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

- What is the target framework for class libraries? It should be .NET Framework 3.5?
- You may need to include those assemblies in Package.xml in Webpart project.

Hope this helps..

Comment: Both class libraries are 3.5.
I have included the assemblies. 

Here is the XML...

  <Assembly Location="ClassLibrary1.dll" DeploymentTarget="GlobalAssemblyCache" />
  <Assembly Location="ClassLibrary2.dll" DeploymentTarget="GlobalAssemblyCache" />